# Troubleshooting Joystick and Controller Issues in ROS Launch File Execution

Tags: ros2, package, ros-control, gazebo-ros-control

"I've already installed the necessary packages for the robot operation and completed the setup in the launch file. However, whenever I run the launch file, the joystick doesn't seem to work, and the controller isn't functioning, causing the robot model not to operate. How can I resolve this? so I use ROS2 humble

Referencing this URL: https://www.youtube.com/watchv=4QKsDf1c4hc&list=PLunhqkrRNRhYAffV8JDiFOatQXuU-NnxT&index=12

When I execute 'ros2 launch articubot_one launch_sim.launch.py world:=src/articubot_one/worlds//obstacles.world', the following events occur."

> [INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/hoonle/.ros/log/2023-12-18-22-28-59-263908-hoonle135-12482
> [INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
> [INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process started with pid [12484]
> [INFO] [joy_node-2]: process started with pid [12486]
> [INFO] [teleop_node-3]: process started with pid [12488]
> [INFO] [twist_mux-4]: process started with pid [12490]
> [INFO] [gzserver-5]: process started with pid [12492]
> [INFO] [gzclient-6]: process started with pid [12495]
> [INFO] [spawn_entity.py-7]: process started with pid [12498]
> [INFO] [spawner-8]: process started with pid [12506]
> [INFO] [spawner-9]: process started with pid [12512]
> [teleop_node-3] [INFO] [1702906145.170786454] [TeleopTwistJoy]: Teleop enable button 6.
> [teleop_node-3] [INFO] [1702906145.183447953] [TeleopTwistJoy]: Turbo on button 7.
> [teleop_node-3] [INFO] [1702906145.183529894] [TeleopTwistJoy]: Linear axis x on 1 at scale 0.500000.
> [teleop_node-3] [INFO] [1702906145.183708446] [TeleopTwistJoy]: Turbo for linear axis x is scale 1.000000.
> [teleop_node-3] [INFO] [1702906145.183757644] [TeleopTwistJoy]: Angular axis yaw on 0 at scale 0.500000.
> [teleop_node-3] [INFO] [1702906145.183791701] [TeleopTwistJoy]: Turbo for angular axis yaw is scale 1.000000.
> [robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1702906145.884653768] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_footprint
> [robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1702906145.885164739] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
> [robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1702906145.885215727] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_link
> [robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1702906145.885238465] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_link_optical
> [robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1702906145.885260016] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment caster_wheel
> [robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1702906145.885280587] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment chassis
> [robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1702906145.885301213] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment face_link
> [robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1702906145.885320870] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment laser_frame
> [robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1702906145.885340244] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment left_wheel
> [robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1702906145.885359744] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment right_wheel
> [twist_mux-4] [INFO] [1702906145.985599794] [twist_mux]: Topic handler 'topics.joystick' subscribed to topic 'cmd_vel_joy': timeout = 0.500000s , priority = 100.
> [twist_mux-4] [INFO] [1702906146.031988853] [twist_mux]: Topic handler 'topics.navigation' subscribed to topic 'cmd_vel': timeout = 0.500000s , priority = 10.
> [twist_mux-4] [INFO] [1702906146.057723243] [twist_mux]: Topic handler 'topics.tracker' subscribed to topic 'cmd_vel_tracker': timeout = 0.500000s , priority = 20.
> [joy_node-2] [INFO] [1702906148.870057931] [joy_node]: Opened joystick: Xbox 360 Controller.  deadzone: 0.050000
> [spawner-8] [INFO] [1702906151.209195415] [spawner_diff_cont]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
> [spawner-9] [INFO] [1702906152.262984379] [spawner_joint_broad]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
> [spawn_entity.py-7] [INFO] [1702906152.431985994] [spawn_entity]: Spawn Entity started
> [spawn_entity.py-7] [INFO] [1702906152.435572264] [spawn_entity]: Loading entity published on topic robot_description
> [spawn_entity.py-7] /opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/qos.py:307: UserWarning: DurabilityPolicy.RMW_QOS_POLICY_DURABILITY_TRANSIENT_LOCAL is deprecated. Use DurabilityPolicy.TRANSIENT_LOCAL instead.
> [spawn_entity.py-7]   warnings.warn(
> [spawn_entity.py-7] [INFO] [1702906152.462296407] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for entity xml on robot_description
> [spawn_entity.py-7] [INFO] [1702906152.483177278] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity, timeout = 30
> [spawn_entity.py-7] [INFO] [1702906152.488030881] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity
> [spawner-8] [INFO] [1702906153.253201370] [spawner_diff_cont]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
> [spawner-9] [INFO] [1702906154.329643129] [spawner_joint_broad]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
> [spawner-8] [INFO] [1702906155.333745837] [spawner_diff_cont]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
> [spawn_entity.py-7] [INFO] [1702906156.038646357] [spawn_entity]: Calling service /spawn_entity
> [spawner-9] [INFO] [1702906156.505024238] [spawner_joint_broad]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
> [spawner-8] [INFO] [1702906157.374522076] [spawner_diff_cont]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
> [gzserver-5] [INFO] [1702906158.511504720] [camera_controller]: Publishing camera info to [/camera/camera_info]
> [spawner-9] [INFO] [1702906158.552936132] [spawner_joint_broad]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
> [gzserver-5] [WARN] [1702906158.714900027] [rcl]: Found remap rule '~/out:=scan'. This syntax is deprecated. Use '--ros-args --remap ~/out:=scan' instead.
> [spawn_entity.py-7] [INFO] [1702906158.786377944] [spawn_entity]: Spawn status: SpawnEntity: Successfully spawned entity [my_bot]
> [spawner-8] [ERROR] [1702906158.918843418] [spawner_diff_cont]: Controller manager not available
> [gzserver-5] [WARN] [1702906159.092505281] [rcl]: Found remap rule '~/out:=scan'. This syntax is deprecated. Use '--ros-args --remap ~/out:=scan' instead.
> [gzserver-5] [INFO] [1702906159.631869569] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading gazebo_ros2_control plugin
> [spawner-9] [ERROR] [1702906159.804731038] [spawner_joint_broad]: Controller manager not available
> [INFO] [spawn_entity.py-7]: process has finished cleanly [pid 12498]
> [gzserver-5] [INFO] [1702906160.131269697] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Starting gazebo_ros2_control plugin in namespace: /
> [gzserver-5] [INFO] [1702906160.134292559] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Starting gazebo_ros2_control plugin in ros 2 node: gazebo_ros2_control
> [gzserver-5] [INFO] [1702906160.137459190] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading parameter files /home/hoonle/dev_ws/install/articubot_one/share/articubot_one/config/my_controllers.yaml
> [gzserver-5] [INFO] [1702906160.142078293] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading parameter files /home/hoonle/dev_ws/install/articubot_one/share/articubot_one/config/gaz_ros2_ctl_use_sim.yaml
> [gzserver-5] [INFO] [1702906160.407563766] [gazebo_ros2_control]: connected to service!! robot_state_publisher
> [gzserver-5] [INFO] [1702906160.413188506] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Received urdf from param server, parsing...
> [ERROR] [spawner-8]: process has died [pid 12506, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner diff_cont --ros-args'].
> [gzserver-5] [INFO] [1702906160.616743943] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading joint: left_wheel_joint
> [gzserver-5] [INFO] [1702906160.617521531] [gazebo_ros2_control]:   State:
> [gzserver-5] [INFO] [1702906160.617592564] [gazebo_ros2_control]:        velocity
> [gzserver-5] [INFO] [1702906160.617631934] [gazebo_ros2_control]:        position
> [gzserver-5] [INFO] [1702906160.617663410] [gazebo_ros2_control]:   Command:
> [gzserver-5] [INFO] [1702906160.617726429] [gazebo_ros2_control]:        velocity
> [gzserver-5] [INFO] [1702906160.617767571] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading joint: right_wheel_joint
> [gzserver-5] [INFO] [1702906160.617797019] [gazebo_ros2_control]:   State:
> [gzserver-5] [INFO] [1702906160.617822631] [gazebo_ros2_control]:        velocity
> [gzserver-5] [INFO] [1702906160.617848121] [gazebo_ros2_control]:        position
> [gzserver-5] [INFO] [1702906160.617872919] [gazebo_ros2_control]:   Command:
> [gzserver-5] [INFO] [1702906160.619132016] [gazebo_ros2_control]:        velocity
> [gzserver-5] [INFO] [1702906160.619361862] [resource_manager]: Initialize hardware 'GazeboSystem'
> [gzserver-5] [INFO] [1702906160.621804402] [resource_manager]: Successful initialization of hardware 'GazeboSystem'
> [gzserver-5] [INFO] [1702906160.622799508] [resource_manager]: 'configure' hardware 'GazeboSystem'
> [gzserver-5] [INFO] [1702906160.622846051] [resource_manager]: Successful 'configure' of hardware 'GazeboSystem'
> [gzserver-5] [INFO] [1702906160.622867518] [resource_manager]: 'activate' hardware 'GazeboSystem'
> [gzserver-5] [INFO] [1702906160.622886590] [resource_manager]: Successful 'activate' of hardware 'GazeboSystem'
> [gzserver-5] [INFO] [1702906160.625476274] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading controller_manager
> [gzserver-5] [INFO] [1702906160.913622535] [controller_manager]: Subscribing to '~/robot_description' topic for robot description file.
> [ERROR] [spawner-9]: process has died [pid 12512, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner joint_broad --ros-args'].
> [gzserver-5] [WARN] [1702906161.118151328] [gazebo_ros2_control]:  Desired controller update period (0.0333333 s) is slower than the gazebo simulation period (0.001 s).
> [gzserver-5] [INFO] [1702906161.121703280] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loaded gazebo_ros2_control.
> [gzclient-6] context mismatch in svga_surface_destroy
> [gzclient-6] context mismatch in svga_surface_destroy

and my controllers yamlfile

> controller_manager:
> ros__parameters:
> update_rate: 30
> # use_sim_time: true

```
diff_cont:
  type: diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController

joint_broad:
  type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster
```

diff_cont:
ros__parameters:

```
publish_rate: 50.0

base_frame_id: base_link

left_wheel_names: ['left_wheel_joint']
right_wheel_names: ['right_wheel_joint']
wheel_separation: 0.297
wheel_radius: 0.033

use_stamped_vel: false

# open_loop: false    

# wheels_per_side: x
# wheel_separation_multiplier: x
# left_wheel_radius_multiplier: x
# right_wheel_radius_multiplier: x

# odom_frame_id: x
# pose_covariance_diagonal: x
# twist_covariance_diagonal: x
# open_loop: x
# enable_odom_tf: x

# cmd_vel_timeout: x
# publish_limited_velocity: x
# velocity_rolling_window_size: x


# linear.x.has_velocity_limits: false
# linear.x.has_acceleration_limits: false
# linear.x.has_jerk_limits: false
# linear.x.max_velocity: NAN
# linear.x.min_velocity: NAN
# linear.x.max_acceleration: NAN
# linear.x.min_acceleration: NAN
# linear.x.max_jerk: NAN
# linear.x.min_jerk: NAN

# angular.z.has_velocity_limits: false
# angular.z.has_acceleration_limits: false
# angular.z.has_jerk_limits: false
# angular.z.max_velocity: NAN
# angular.z.min_velocity: NAN
# angular.z.max_acceleration: NAN
# angular.z.min_acceleration: NAN
# angular.z.max_jerk: NAN
# angular.z.min_jerk: NAN
# joint_broad:
#   ros__parameters:
```

finaly my launch file

```
import os
```

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory

from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource

from launch_ros.actions import Node

def generate_launch_description():

```
# Include the robot_state_publisher launch file, provided by our own package. Force sim time to be enabled
# !!! MAKE SURE YOU SET THE PACKAGE NAME CORRECTLY !!!

package_name='articubot_one' #<--- CHANGE ME

rsp = IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
                get_package_share_directory(package_name),'launch','rsp.launch.py'
            )]), launch_arguments={'use_sim_time': 'true', 'use_ros2_control': 'true'}.items()
)

joystick = IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
                get_package_share_directory(package_name),'launch','joystick.launch.py'
            )]), launch_arguments={'use_sim_time': 'true'}.items()
)

twist_mux_params = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(package_name),'config','twist_mux.yaml')
twist_mux = Node(
        package="twist_mux",
        executable="twist_mux",
        parameters=[twist_mux_params, {'use_sim_time': True}],
        remappings=[('/cmd_vel_out','/diff_cont/cmd_vel_unstamped')]
    )

gazebo_params_file = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(package_name),'config','gazebo_params.yaml')

# Include the Gazebo launch file, provided by the gazebo_ros package
gazebo = IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
                get_package_share_directory('gazebo_ros'), 'launch', 'gazebo.launch.py')]),
                launch_arguments={'extra_gazebo_args': '--ros-args --params-file ' + gazebo_params_file}.items()
         )

# Run the spawner node from the gazebo_ros package. The entity name doesn't really matter if you only have a single robot.
spawn_entity = Node(package='gazebo_ros', executable='spawn_entity.py',
                    arguments=['-topic', 'robot_description',
                               '-entity', 'my_bot'],
                    output='screen')


diff_drive_spawner = Node(
    package="controller_manager",
    executable="spawner",
    arguments=["diff_cont"],
)

joint_broad_spawner = Node(
    package="controller_manager",
    executable="spawner",
    arguments=["joint_broad"],
)


# Code for delaying a node (I haven't tested how effective it is)
# 
# First add the below lines to imports
# from launch.actions import RegisterEventHandler
# from launch.event_handlers import OnProcessExit
#
# Then add the following below the current diff_drive_spawner
# delayed_diff_drive_spawner = RegisterEventHandler(
#     event_handler=OnProcessExit(
#         target_action=spawn_entity,
#         on_exit=[diff_drive_spawner],
#     )
# )
#
# Replace the diff_drive_spawner in the final return with delayed_diff_drive_spawner



# Launch them all!
return LaunchDescription([
    rsp,
    joystick,
    twist_mux,
    gazebo,
    spawn_entity,
    diff_drive_spawner,
    joint_broad_spawner
])
```

this is my list hardware interfaces

```
hoonle@hoonle135:~/dev_ws$ ros2 control list_hardware_interfaces
command interfaces
left_wheel_joint/velocity [available] [unclaimed]
right_wheel_joint/velocity [available] [unclaimed]
state interfaces
left_wheel_joint/position
left_wheel_joint/velocity
right_wheel_joint/position
right_wheel_joint/velocity
hoonle@hoonle135:~/dev_ws$ ros2 run controller_manager spawner.py diff_cont
```

No executable found

I would really appreciate your assistance. Could you please help me?

Comment: I think there's some formatting issues here: the error log doesn't have any newlines and some of your code snippets seem to not be indented correctly for formatting. Could you take a look at that so the information you're providing is clearer?

Answer (score 0):

It may be an issue of topics. What topic is your controller listening to? Is it /cmd_vel? The robot and Ros_control must be in agreement here, working with the same topic name. And your teleop_twist_joy module must publish the same topic. It's easy to set in the params file.

Comment: This issue has already been resolved.
Thank you for your help!